# Prevent to crash bc. missing access rights

Tags: swift, crash, try-catch, throw

I have a folder, I like to be opened  by NSWorkspace. But if access rights are missing, the entire app is crashing.
How can I aviod this and show a message, that access rights were missing?
I tried "try-catch", but this function does not throw errors!

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(urlOutput)   // this could crash
```

Comment: Error message? Crash log? According to the documentation this method should return false if the file cannot be opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [isReadableFile](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1418292-isreadablefile) method in `FileManager`.

```
if FileManager.isReadableFile(atPath: urlOutput.path) {
     NSWorkspace.shared.open(urlOutput)
    
} else {
     //Show an Error Message
}
```

Comment: @Peter71 At best this is a workaround but doesn't resolve the issue with the crash.

Comment: If I avoid calling the crashing function, that's the solution.